# Is that possible to install Hadoop on a linux box and try most of (if not all of) the Hadoop utilities?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to learn Hadoop, is that possible to install Hadoop on a linux box and try most of (if not all of) the Hadoop utilities?

Comment: can you tell us what you decided to do? i am in the same boat and i think i will download the cloudera vm

Comment: Check out http://openscg.com/se/bigsql/ Easy to install Hadoop and Postgres Bundles for Linux 64 and OSX 64. Tutorial and scripts to quickly get up and running in Pseudo distributed mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

Hadoop can run in two modes locally:

- Standalone mode -- nothing starts up, you can run hadoop jobs locally off of local files.
- Pseudo-distributed mode -- Effectively distributed mode, but all of the daemons start up locally on one node.

How to set these up and get started with them is [documented on the hadoop page](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html).

Since you say you want to try Hadoop utilities, you probably want to try out pseudo-distributed mode. When using the command line tools, mapreduce jobs, pig, hive, etc., a local cluster running in pseudo-distributed mode will look like a 1000 node cluster (except that it can't hold as much data).

Answer (score 3):

You can download CDH3 virtual machine from cloudera.(https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera's+Hadoop+Demo+VM) and have everything integrated in one VM. IMHO It is a simplest way to start with hadoop.

Comment: hi david! have you done this yourself? can you tell us about your experience?

Comment: I did it, and it is common practice in many companies. It is very smooth expirance - you just run it and have HDFS, MR, Hive, HBase working.

Comment: hi david! i've installed it but am lost on what to do next! can you guide me?

Comment: I would suggest Hadoop Definitive Guide as a way to go

Comment: great! does it tell you how to set things up with services/hosts on cloudera?

Comment: It is more about concepts of MR. Installation good instructions are here: https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Installation

Comment: thanks! i downloaded the VM with cloudera already on it, do i still need to install more stuff? sorry for dumb questions, i just have no clue what i am doing

Comment: Everything is installed there and configured.

Comment: great! do i need to add a cluster or create a new host from the cloudera manager? chanukah sameach!

Comment: david, i asked this question just now: http://serverfault.com/questions/456825/installing-hosts-for-cloudera-on-virtualbox